# 404 page when defining Controller and Action in custom PHP MVC in IIS

Tags: php, model-view-controller, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config

I am building a custom PHP MVC framework based on http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw28-krO7ZM (Create Your Own MVC - Jream), however I am using IIS as my local webserver.  I have installed the Url Rewrite Module and added the following rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="MyRewriteRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
```

The MVC is structured as follows:

```
application(folder)
   config(folder), controllers(folder), view(folder), model(folder) etc...
public(folder)
   css, images, js, etc...
index.php
web.config
```

The url `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/` works just fine but `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index/` fails...or `/home`, `/legal` any controller for that matter.  In the custom Bootstrap.php file the following code executes:

```
<?php class Bootstrap{
   function __construct(){
      //format the url
      $url=isset($_GET['url'])? $_GET['url']: null; //when a controller is specified it fails before even hitting this point, im sent to the error 404 page before getting past here
      $url=rtrim($url,'/');
      $url=explode('/',$url);

      if(empty($url[0])){
         require 'application/controllers/index.php';
         //.....blah blah blah
      }
        //more irrelevant code...
         require 'application/controllers/'.url[0]'.php';
      //more irrelevant code...
     }} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start changing

`require 'application/controllers/'.url[0]'.php';`

to

`require 'application/controllers/'.$url[0]'.php';`